# Interest rate, bond problem

Tags: interest-rate, bonds

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> Debtor issued a bond on 20 000€ (including interest rate) with
>   maturity rate of 8 months and interest rate of 8% per annum. Month
>   later, the creditor sold the bond to a different person, who discount
>   the bond with 9% interest rate p.a.
>
> How much did the creditor receive for the bond?

My solution is the following:

$FutureValue$ $= P(1+i*t*t/12) = 20000(1+0,08*8*8/12) = 28533$

Is it correct? Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to figure out the future value initially or the price that the bond was sold for?